# Why can I not use the public methods from other classes on an object that I got from a HashMap?

Tags: java, inheritance, dictionary, hashmap, polymorphism

I have a class called `Pizza` that looks like this:

```
public class Pizza extends MenuItem
{ 
    private final String base;

    public String getBase()
    {
        return base;
    }
}
```

My base class `MenuItem` has a method called `addItem()` that looks like this:

```
 public static void addItem(String menuItemNumber, MenuItem menuItem)
    {
        itemsMap.put(menuItemNumber, menuItem); //itemsMap is a class HashMap
        itemsSet = itemsMap.entrySet();
        System.out.println(itemsSet); //this prints the object's reference
        MenuItem pizza = (itemsMap.get("1"));
        System.out.println(pizza.getBase());//Problem is in this line
```

Why can I not use `pizza` here to invoke `getBase()`?

Comment: Side note: The outermost `()` in `MenuItem pizza = (itemsMap.get("1"));` have no function at all. It's exactly the same as `MenuItem pizza = itemsMap.get("1");`

Comment: @T.J.Crowder I did know that and they're not in my actual code. Put them in for some reason when I copied here. Thanks for the heads-up anyway.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Because you've declared the `pizza` variable as `MenuItem`, not `Pizza`. So the reference you have to it is typed `MenuItem`, and you can only use the `MenuItem` methods. Since `getBase` is provided by `Pizza`, not `MenuItem`, you can't use it without doing something more.

If you change this line:

```
MenuItem pizza = (itemsMap.get("1"));
```

to

```
Pizza pizza = itemsMap.get("1");
```

*(those outermost `()` weren't doing anything)* then you can use `getBase`.

If `itemsMap` is declared as `Map<String, MenuItem>`, you'll need a cast:

```
Pizza pizza = (Pizza)itemsMap.get("1");
```

or even a guard:

```
MenuItem mi = itemsMap.get("1");
if (mi instanceof Pizza) {
    System.out.println(((Pizza)mi).getBase());
}
```

Comment: I tried changing `MenuItem Pizza` to `Pizza Pizza`, but didn't realise I'd need that cast because of the map declaration. Thanks.